# I need to group items in a table by multiple fields and sum values while doing so

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq

I have the following table that I've joined from a couple of others...

```
+------------+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+  
|         Id | SubscriberId | CashAmount |        DateTime         | SubscriberId |  Email  |  
+------------+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+  
|          7 |            3 | 32.00      | 2014-05-06 16:19:00.000 |            3 | k@k.com |  
|         67 |            3 | 32.00      | 2014-06-22 11:34:00.000 |            3 | k@k.com |  
|         68 |            4 | 12.00      | 2014-04-22 15:34:00.000 |            4 | b@b.com |  
|         69 |            4 | 32.00      | 2014-05-06 16:20:00.000 |            4 | b@b.com |  
|         70 |            5 | 2.00       | 2014-05-22 11:34:00.000 |            5 | c@c.com |  
|         71 |            6 | 32.00      | 2014-06-22 11:34:00.000 |            6 | b@b.com |  
|         72 |            7 | 12.00      | 2014-05-22 11:34:00.000 |            7 | a@a.com |  
|         73 |            4 | 12.00      | 2014-06-22 11:34:00.000 |            4 | b@b.com |  
|         74 |            6 | 12.00      | 2014-04-22 15:34:00.000 |            6 | b@b.com |  
|         75 |            4 | 32.00      | 2014-04-22 15:34:00.000 |            4 | b@b.com |  
|         76 |            4 | 6.00       | 2014-04-22 15:34:00.000 |            4 | b@b.com |  
+------------+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

I need to group these records using Linq in .NET into unique months. Furthermore, each unique month should have a list of unique subscribers with the total donation for that month summed (since one user can donate many times in one month). This is deeper that I'm sure how to handle with my knowledge of SQL or Linq. For the record, since I'm using linq, the DateTime object from the EntitySet has a Month and Year object. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult>>)` operator like this:

```
var result = dbContext.Subscriptions.GroupBy(item => new {
      Year = item.DateTime.Year,
      Month = item.DateTime.Month,
      SubscriberId = item.SubscriberId,
  },
  (key, items) => new {
      Year = key.Year,
      Month = key.Month,
      SubscriberId = key.SubscriberId,
      CashAmount = items.Sum(item => item.CashAmount)
  });
```